# Putting same income for same groupID

Tags: stata

In my data, income was asked only to one person of the group.

```
householdID   memberID  income
  1              1        4
  2              2        .
  1              2        .
  2              3        .
  2              1        3
```

But obviously, I need to fill them up like

```
householdID   memberID  income
  1              1        4
  2              2        3
  1              2        4
  2              3        3
  2              1        3
```

How can I do this in Stata?

Comment: Good questions here show some attempt at code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an elementary application of `by:`

```
bysort householdID (income) : replace income = income[1] if missing(income)
```

See for related material [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/)

A more circumspect approach would check that at most one non-missing value has been supplied for each household:

```
bysort householdID (income) : gen OK = missing(income) | (income == income[1])  
list if !OK
```